# How to fill a list into incoherence cells of column

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to insert code from Column A to **Blank cell** in Column C sequentially? (I have so many code so cannot copy and past manually),

[image]

the result should be:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you researched or attempted so far?

Comment: Check out [this page](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html). It may help you get started.

Comment: thanks but your link is not match my question, your link is just fill blank cells the same value with above, while I need fill with the provided list

Comment: The ***[help]*** can help you understand how this site works. The link I gave was to help you find a way to accomplish it, not do it for you. Your question may not be getting any answers because it shows no effort on your part. This is not a service site where you place orders for what you want done. So, to improve your question, ***[edit]*** it with what you have attempted and researched so far so we can help you where you get stuck.